# Anaconda Python IDE for Sublime Text 3 - Can't get documentation for libraries installed only in local virtual environment

Tags: sublimetext3, virtualenv, sublime-text-plugin, sublime-anaconda

Just set up Anaconda Package for Sublime Text 3 and everything is working as expected.  I can access documentation strings via `ctrl + alt + d`, but only for classes/functions that belong to globally-installed python libraries.  For items belonging to libraries only installed in my virtualenv, doc strings don't work.

Following the [docs](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/) (see bottom of page), I've created a `.anaconda` file with the following json:

```
{
    "extra_paths": [
        "/Users/me/my_project/lib/python3.5"
    ]
}
```

But doc strings still don't appear for libraries located here.

Any suggestions are appreciated!  Thanks in advance.